# Result that corresponds with customer and date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How will I get the all the date even though there is no order between two dates?

Sample Table

```
OrderID  | Date      | CusID
33942    | 6-21-2014 | 6005
34059    | 6-20-2014 | 4003
53333    | 6-23-2014 | 6005
59234    | 6-23-2014 | 4003
```

How I could have this result?

```
CusID   | Date      | OrderID |
4003    | 6-20-2014 | 34059   | 
4003    | 6-21-2014 | null    | 
4003    | 6-22-2014 | null    | 
4003    | 6-23-2014 | 59234   | 
6005    | 6-20-2014 | null    | 
6005    | 6-21-2014 | 33942   | 
6005    | 6-22-2014 | null    | 
6005    | 6-23-2014 | 53333   |
```

This what I did so far.

I create a calendar table

```
CREATE TABLE #Calendar
(
    [CalendarDate] DATETIME
)

DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME
SET @EndDate = GETDATE()
SET @StartDate = DATEADD(Year, -1, @EndDate)


WHILE @StartDate <= @EndDate
      BEGIN
             INSERT INTO #Calendar
             (
                   CalendarDate
             )
             SELECT
                   @StartDate

             SET @StartDate = DATEADD(dd, 1, @StartDate)
      END
```

Then here is my query but does not give me the needed result

```
Select t.CusID, c.CalendarDate, t.OrderID 
From #Calendar c 
left outer join
#temp t
ON
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), c.CalendarDate, 112) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), t.Date, 112)
Where c.CalendarDate Between '6-20-2014' and '6-23-2014'
Order By t.Name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, your calendar table is broken.  You are using a datetime stamp, and capturing the current time stamp in your table.  Better to write the correct data, than handle it later.

Two fixes for this, use a `DATE` format or `convert` your date to remove the timestamp.  I chose the latter.

From there, you narrow down to the # of days being queried, and the # of customers in those days and generate a cross join of those two subsets.

```
DECLARE @ORDER TABLE (ORDERID INT, ordDATE DATETIME, CUSID INT)
INSERT INTO @ORDER (ORDERID, ordDATE, CUSID)
VALUES (33942,'6-21-2014', 6005), 
       (34059,'6-20-2014',4003), 
       (53333,'6-23-2014',6005), 
       (59234,'6-23-2014',4003)

declare @Calendar table ([CalendarDate] DATETIME)

DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME
SET @EndDate = GETDATE()
SET @StartDate = DATEADD(Year, -1, @EndDate)

WHILE @StartDate <= @EndDate
      BEGIN
             INSERT INTO @Calendar
             (
                   CalendarDate
             )
             SELECT
                   CONVERT(DATETIME,FLOOR(CONVERT(FLOAT, @StartDate)))

             SET @StartDate = DATEADD(dd, 1, @StartDate)
      END 

; with dates as
(
   SELECT DISTINCT CalendarDate
   FROM @Calendar
   WHERE CalendarDate BETWEEN '2014-06-20' AND '2014-06-23'
),
orders as
(
    SELECT DISTINCT CUSID
    FROM @ORDER
    WHERE ordDATE BETWEEN '2014-06-20' AND '2014-06-23'
),
cp AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM dates
    CROSS JOIN orders
)

SELECT cp.CUSID, cp.CalendarDate, O.ORDERID
FROM CP
LEFT OUTER JOIN @ORDER O 
   ON cp.CalendarDate = O.ordDATE 
   AND cp.CUSID = O.CUSID
```

If you wanted, you could move the `WHERE` clause outside the CTEs and into the final `select` statement, but the resulting `cp` table will be significantly larger, and slower on big datasets.

Answer (score 0):

create the cartesian product of dates and customers and then join

```
with cte as 
(
    select caldate, custid
    from calendar, customers
)
select *
from cte
left join temp o 
on cte.custid = o.custid
and cast(caldate as date) = cast(orderdate as date)
where caldate between '20140620' and '20140623'
```